# Fancybox - How to make whatever is out of the box black?

Tags: fancybox

I don't know much about Fancybox, and I'm confused about all the files. I think I have an easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer online. Must be so easy no one ever asks, or I'm  not good at searching online.

I'm using Fancybox with an iframe, and was wondering how I could the stuff that's outside of the fancybox to be all black? I only want the iframe to be visible, or maybe make the outside 90% black. Where would I do this? In what file? There are so many files.

I have another question. How can I make the iframe close by clicking anywhere? I remember it was like this at first, and then I changed it so that it only closes by clicking on the X. I don't remember what file I modified. :/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you open fancybox with a html like:

```
<a href="page.html" class="fancybox">open page</a>
```

No need to modify any file, just add the right options (**for fancybox v1.3.4**) to your custom script like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 "overlayColor": "#000",  // here you set the background black
 "overlayOpacity": 1,  // here you set the transparency of background: 1 = opaque
 "hideOnOverlayClick": true,  // if true, closes fancybox when clicking OUTSIDE the box
 "hideOnContentClick": true, // if true, closes fancybox when clicking INSIDE the box
 "type": "iframe" // the type of content : iframe for external pages
 "width": 640, // if type=iframe is always smart to set dimensions
 "height": 320
});
```

Notice that `Boolean` and/or `integer` values shouldn't have quotes

For other options [read the documentation](http://fancybox.net/api)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [fancybox V2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

You can see in this file: jquery.fancybox.css

Find :

```
    /* Overlay helper */

#fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1001;
    background: #000;
}
```

add:

```
opacity: 1 !important;
```

Opacity is a double value so if you want 90% opacity it's: 0.90

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using Fancybox 1.3.4, and it worked but the color is always gray even when changing background color. Maybe background is for something else then?

Comment: You need to add the !important statement to the background to if you want to overwrite it.